# Spring batch job testing with jUnit always throwing me NullPointerException

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, junit, spring-batch

I'm trying to test a job in spring batch with jUnit and I don't know how to solve that error.

I have this class

**ParametersValidatorService**

```
@Service("parametersValidator")
public class ParametersValidatorService implements IParameterValidatorService {

/**
 * The Constant LOGGER.
 */
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParametersValidatorService.class);

/**
 * Array con los parametros obligatorios.
 */
private static final String[] PARAMETROS_OBLIGATORIOS = new String[]{
        "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6", "val7"
};

/**
 * Array con los parametros que deben ser numericos.
 */
private static final String[] PARAMETROS_NUMERICOS = new String[]{
        "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"};

/**
 * @param jobId:      the job id
 * @param parameters: input job parameters
 * ParametersValidatorException: manages exceptions related with input parameters.
 */
@Override
public void validate(final String jobId, final JobParameters parameters) throws ParametersValidatorException {
    try {
        validate(parameters);
    } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
        throw new ParametersValidatorException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * @param parameters: input job parameters
 * JobParametersInvalidException: manages exceptions related with input parameters.
 */
@Override
public void validate(final JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {
    validarParametros(parameters);
}


/**
 * Comprueba que los parámetros no estén vacíos y que los que tienen que ser numéricos, sean numéricos
 *
 * @param parameters: input job parameters
 * JobParametersInvalidException: manages exceptions related with input parameters.
 */
private void validarParametros(final JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {

    List<String> numericParameters = Arrays.asList(PARAMETROS_NUMERICOS);
    String error = null;
    for (String validacion : PARAMETROS_OBLIGATORIOS) {

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(parameters.getString(validacion))) {
            error = "El parametro " + validacion + " es obligatorio";
        } else if (numericParameters.contains(validacion) && !StringUtils.isNumeric(parameters.getString(validacion))) {
            error = "El parametro " + validacion + " debe ser numerico";
        }
        if (error != null) {
            LOGGER.error(error);
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException(error);
        }
    }
}

}
```

I'm trying to test that with jUnit4 but I'm not able to execute it correctly. I've made this test

**ParametersValidatorServiceTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ParametersValidatorServiceTest {


//@Autowired
@Bean
public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
    return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
}


@Test
public void testLaunchJobOK() throws Exception {

    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("val1", "1")
                                                            .addString("val2", "Nombre de prueba")
                                                            .addString("val3", "61").addString("val6", "1")
                                                            .addString("val4", "RCVD").addString("val7", "43")
                                                            .addString("val5", "2017-05-10 10:48:42").toJobParameter

    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils().launchJob(jobParameters);
    Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode(), jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());

}

}
```

I'm always receiving a java.lang.NullPointerException as seen below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:152)
at com.bbva.kyob.respuestasob.services.impl.ParametersValidatorServiceTest.testLaunchJobOK(ParametersValidatorServiceTest.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

When I do a debug of the test, I see that the parameters I'm entering are being collected and stored in the jobParameters so I don't know what's happening

Comment: Could you split your `launchJob()` line into a declaration and execution to see if `JobLauncherTestUtils` is created correctly?

Comment: You are declaring an `@Bean JobLauncherTestUtils`, but there is no `@Bean` for `ParametersValidatorService`. Are you missing that? What happens in line 152 of `JobLauncherTestUtils`? Might there be a `null ParametersValidatorService`?

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, there is no reference to any job in the `ParametersValidatorServiceTest` class right? So when you execute this statement:

```
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils().launchJob(jobParameters);
```

Which job should be launched? The job is actually [a dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtils.java#L89-L92) of `JobLauncherTestUtils`. That's why it should be defined in your test context to be correctly autowired in `JobLauncherTestUtils`. For example, you can import a configuration class that contains its definition:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyJobConfiguration.class}) // contains the job bean under test
public class ParametersValidatorServiceTest {
   // ...
}
```

Hope this helps.